# Bootstrap is murdering Backbone/Marionette view events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, marionette

Backbone view event block binds perfect and awesome until you call a boot strap method on an element.  Let's say you have this in your view:

```
events: { 'click .menu li.edit': '_doSomething' }
```

Then later on you have a bootstrap thing:

```
$('.menu', this.$el).dropdown('toggle');
```

There is a line in bootstrap.js:

```
var $el = $(element).on('click.dropdown.data-api', this.toggle)
```

...which kills the backbone bound events.

How are people handling this?  I would prefer to keep doing things "the backbone way".  I would hate to handle somethings in the app "the bootstap way" and others "the backbone way".  I like consistency.

Thoughts?

Comment: can you provide a complete JSFiddle or JSBin that reproduces the problem? I've used Backbone and Bootstrap together dozens of times and have never had this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I Actually went for just using the underlying Backbone styles.

For instance my drop down menus use the Backbone classes but not any of the linking data  attributes.  In my view I trigger the style change that backbone.js would have done.

```
class App.Views.Articles.Index.Controls extends Backbone.Marionette.Layout
  template: JST['articles/index/controls']

  regions:
    pager: '#pager'

  ui:
    search_text: '#search-text'
    add_dropdown: '#add'
    add_dropdown_menu: '#add-dropdown-menu'

  events:
    'click #search-button': 'doSearch'
    'click #add': 'toggleAddDropDown'



  toggleAddDropDown: (event) ->
    event.stopPropagation()
    if @ui.add_dropdown.hasClass('open')
      @ui.add_dropdown_menu.fadeOut('fast')
      @ui.add_dropdown.removeClass('open')
    else
      @ui.add_dropdown.addClass('open')
      @ui.add_dropdown_menu.fadeIn('fast')
```